# Console entry points not working with the --target argument with pip install

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I've installed a module with the `--target` argument and the console entry points are installed at the target in a /bin directory. Therefore they are not accessible via the command line. Usually they would install to `/usr/bin`.

I've tried adding `--install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/bin"` but the behaviour doesn't change.

The full install command that doesn't install the entry points to /usr/bin:
`/usr/bin/pip install my-package-1.0.0-py2-none-any.whl --target /opt/myproject/ --upgrade --install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/bin"`

TIA

Comment: This won't work because you are installing from a wheel. When using `--install-scripts`, `pip` will warn you about it being unable to use wheels. Build a source distribution of `my-package` (`python setup.py sdist`) and pass the resulting file to `pip` instead of the wheel for your command to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `--target` you're on your own. Add `/opt/myproject/bin` to `$PATH` and `/opt/myproject/lib/pythonX.Y` to `$PYTHONPATH`.